# Flutter Application showing blank screen when trying to invoke a Future Builder

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a futureBuilder with a Future Function that I have which passes through a list of objects which contain the surveyName parameter, I am trying to display that surveyName descriptor into a listView but am noticing that I am getting a blank white screen that isn't showing both the container which is just supposed to show some basic loading functionality and it isn't displaying the information of the getSurveys function either.

I am new to both dart and flutter, so this may just have some basic simple resolution but any information would be helpful. The method getSurveys below in the print displays both names in the print so I know the information is coming in correct for that specific function but I am wondering why it isn't working within the futureBuilder.

The 1 and 2 print statements are running but I am noticing the 3 print statement isn't so that listView  Builder is not being invoked for some starnge reason, which may be the cause of this dilemma but I wonder why the container which is just supposed to showcase a loading... is not working correctly either. Output is below this function.

```
Future<List<Survey_List>> getSurveys() async{
  Map map = {
    'Type': "getSurveys"
  };
  var _list = [];
  List<Survey_List> surveys = [];
  getPost(map).then((Map value){
    _list.addAll(value["survey"]);

    for (int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++){
      Survey_List survey_list = Survey_List(surveyName: _list[i].toString() ,surveyDescription: "", surveyVersion: "");
      surveys.add(survey_list);
      print(survey_list.surveyName);
    }
  });

  return surveys;
}
```

**Output is** as follows:

```
I/flutter ( 2020): 2

I/flutter ( 2020): 1

I/flutter ( 2020): {"survey":["Survey","Surve3ww"]}

I/flutter ( 2020): Survey

I/flutter ( 2020): Surve3ww
```

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application/Http.dart';
import 'Config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Survey_List extends StatefulWidget {
  String surveyName;
  String surveyDescription;
  String surveyVersion;

  Survey_List({
    this.surveyName,
    this.surveyDescription,
    this.surveyVersion,
    Key key,
  }) : super (key: key);
  @override
  _SurveyListState createState() => _SurveyListState();
}

class _SurveyListState extends State<Survey_List> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Surveys"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new FutureBuilder <List<Survey_List>>(
          future: getSurveys(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            List<Survey_List> surveys = snapshot.data;
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(1);
              return new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  print(3);
                  Survey_List survey_list = surveys[index];
                  print(survey_list.toString());
                  return new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(survey_list.surveyName)
                  );
                },
              );
            }
            else{
              print(2);
              return new Container(
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text("Loading...")
                )
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `snapshot.data.length`?

Comment: Are you referring to the itemCount? I was following some tutorials for FutureBuilder that had snapshot.data.length as the itemCount parameter.

Comment: yeas, i am referring to `itemCount`, is it > 0?

Comment: I can't print out the snapshot.data.length since it doesn't go below that, just as it doesn't use the print(3) as well. I am wondering why it isn't invoking that listView Builder to execute any code within it. If working correctly, it should take both names and have a length of 2 but I can't tell if it's working as intended at all.

Comment: simply add `print(snapshot.data.length);` after `print(1);` - what do you see now?

Comment: Ahh, that brings me closer to a solution. It is showing 0 as the length

Comment: so you have the answer

Comment: but why is it displaying 0 as the length when I am passing through a list of objects which should contain information as the function does work.

Comment: I only see it just a single time.

Comment: instead of `getPost(map).then((Map value) {` simply use `Map value = await getPost(map)`

Comment: Wow, thank you @pskink, I took a break and came back not ready for a solution but that was it. I wish I could give you an answer thing but i'll just let this thread die I guess. You have saved my life of hours of work.

Comment: sure, your welcome, for more read this: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await